# Make feature depend on two other features

Tags: wix

I am creating an installer that contains two features: A and B. When both A and B is installed, I want to implicitly install a third feature: C.

To understand why I want to do this, A and B are unrelated components, and C is the "glue" feature that connects A and B. Since A and B are in reality a lot of optional components, I want to hide this complexity from the user and just install the C component whenever A and B are selected.

I think I can use the `Condition` element to do this, but my naive approach (`(&A=3) AND (&B=3)`) does not work. What is the most straightforward solution to this?

Comment: It's possibly kicking the can down the road, but you could consider making at least C it's own MSI and using a [WiX bootstrapper](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) to install/uninstall A, B, ABC using an [InstallCondition](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html) on C. But, if you ended up having to write your own WiX bootstrapper application, then it would be the equivalent of @Chris's Option 3.

Answer (score 2):

MSI doesn't really support this.  I suggest one of several approaches.

Option 1 - Have all the components for feature C belong to features A and B also.

Option 2-  Have feature C be a parent feature of features A and B.  You must install C in order to install sub features A or B.

Option 3- Have features A B and C as siblings and use custom actions to enforce a business rule that if A or B is selected C must be installed.

Personally I'd go with option 2.  #1 if you really want to hide the existance of C.  It depends on your scenario.  Option 3 is for more complex scenarios and is less pure.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, I am trying to accomplish the "and" case, not the "or" case (otherwise option #1 would be a perfect match). But I suspect the first sentence is the answer, MSI has no native way of doing this.

Comment: Would your code allow for some dependency injection?   Could you lay feature C components down with A or B and go dormant unless components (say XML or Registry config data)  from both A and B are present?

Comment: The C components *could* be installed with either A *or* B, but as they only make sense when both exists, I would *prefer* if they were only present when both features are present, because the C components may in turn have other dependencies causing the installation to be quite large.